# Grok custom pattern - how to match specific domain format

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to match just this part `*.server.domain.com*` from the log below and assign to domain variable. Any idea how pattern should look like, default `HOSTNAME` pattern does not work for me.

```
Apr  4 10:46:25 10.42.203.245 ThreatInsightAnalytics[29407]: The CNAME record '*.server.domain.com' is successfully added into BlackList RPZ zone(s) with comment '[2018-04-04 10:46:22 UTC] [member: infoblox.localdomain] DNS Tunneling' and policy 'No Such Domain'.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Oniguruma syntax to add an `asterisk` and a `.` in pre-defined grok pattern for the `HOSTNAME` and create a custom pattern as follows,

```
(?<domain_name>\*\.)%{HOSTNAME}
```

OR

```
(?<domain_name>\*\.\b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b))
```

This will produce following output on your log,

```
{
  "domain_name": [
    [
      "*.server.domain.com"
    ]
  ]
}
```

hope it helps